# change row data to column with out using Pivot function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am trying to Pivot table data

```
    Create table strategy(date date,[event] varchar(100),eType varchar(100))
    insert into  dbo.strategy (DATE, [event], eType) values
    ('1 Jan 2018' , 'ABZPD', 'dev'),
    ('1 Jan 2018', 'BFSPD', 'stage'),
    ('1 Jan 2018', 'BFSPD', 'pre-dep');


select * from strategy
```

Expected output:

| DATE | ABZPD | BFSPD | BFSZH | BHXPD | BHXZH | BRSZH | BRUPQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | dev | stage | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2018-01-01 | NULL | pre-dep | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Below Code I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
(
  SELECT DATE
               ,[event]
               ,eType 
          FROM  [strategy] 
          where datename(year, DATE) = 2018 or datename(year,DATE)=2019
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(eType)
          FOR event  IN ([ABZPD],[BFSPD]
,[BFSZH]
,[BHXPD]
,[BHXZH]
,[BRSZH]
,[BRUPQ] )  
) AS PivotTable;  



drop table strategy
```

Below is the output I am getting :

| DATE | ABZPD | BFSPD | BFSZH | BHXPD | BHXZH | BRSZH | BRUPQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | dev | stage | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Why `dev` belongs to the first record and not to the second one? That's why you are not getting what you expect, because pivot works using implicit aggregation, and you cannot have 2 maximum values for the same date

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding ROW_NUMBER to your query, but anyways - you pivot for MAX(etype), so the result you showed was correct... what exactly do you want to achieve with the query? The expected result looks a bit odd... however, following an example with Rownumber:

```
DECLARE @strategy TABLE(date date,[event] varchar(100),eType varchar(100))

insert into  @strategy (DATE, [event], eType) values
('1 Jan 2018' , 'ABZPD', 'dev'),
('1 Jan 2018', 'BFSPD', 'stage'),
('1 Jan 2018', 'BFSPD', 'pre-dep');


WITH cteStrategy AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, event ORDER BY eType) rn
  FROM @strategy
)
SELECT * 
FROM  
(
  SELECT DATE
               ,[event]
               ,eType 
               ,rn
          FROM  cteStrategy 
          where datename(year, DATE) = 2018 or datename(year,DATE)=2019
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(eType)
          FOR event  IN ([ABZPD],[BFSPD]
,[BFSZH]
,[BHXPD]
,[BHXZH]
,[BRSZH]
,[BRUPQ] )  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select date,
       max(case when event = 'ABZPD' then eType end) as ABZPD,
       max(case when event = 'BFSPD' then eType end) as BFSPD,
       max(case when event = 'BFSZH' then eType end) as BFSZH,
       max(case when event = 'BHXPD' then eType end) as BHXPD,
       max(case when event = 'BHXZH' then eType end) as BHXZH,
       max(case when event = 'BRUPQ' then eType end) as BRUPQ
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as seqnum
      from strategy s
      where date >= '2018-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01'
     ) s
group by date, seqnum;
```

Note in particular the change to how the dates are filtered.  `datename()` returns a string and you are comparing that string to a number.  Don't mix data types!  Date ranges are usually better for string comparisons anyway.

I have a preference for conditional aggregation over bespoke `pivot` functionality, because aggregation is much more flexible.